# AT jobs not running

Tags: cron, scheduled-task, task-scheduler, at

Ubuntu 10.04 Server

I am using `at` to have a `bash` script schedule itself to run again a particular interval after it completes: (here is the last line of that script)

```
echo "$0" | at tomorrow + 5minutes
```

The job gets scheduled, but does not run. When I run `atq`, I see the job is scheduled, but it is now well past the time it should have run:

```
9       Sat Jun  4 11:38:00 2011 = username
```

Time now:
`$ date`

```
Sat Jun  4 22:55:09 EDT 2011
```

Nothing shows up in my CRON log about it. Is there some other log it would show up in? Is there some way I can force it to run? Google has not been very helpful, since it does not understand that at is the name of a program...

Edit: The job probably did not run because of a broken Ubuntu update:

```
Jun  4 11:38:00 server01 atd[32330]: Module is unknown
```

http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=39867
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/790538

Now that is fixed, what is the best way to run the job manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job probably did not run because of a broken Ubuntu update:

```
Jun  4 11:38:00 server01 atd[32330]: Module is unknown
```

References:

- http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=39867
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/790538

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that `atd` is not running?

```
ps -ef|grep atd
```

This is a bit of a long shot because you would get a warning from the `at` command if the daemon were not running.

Comment: `daemon    2036     1  0 May09 ?        00:00:00 atd`

Comment: @yakatz: That looks fine. Sorry, I don't think I can help.